# Use or non-use of the definite article before a proper noun in an appositive phrase

Tags: articles, appositives

> This study compares the immunotoxic effects of repeated administration of two monoclonal antibodies, **the ABC-12** (RusBio, lot #1023) and Herceptin (Hoffmann-La Roche, Switzerland), to rhesus macaques (Macaca mulatta).

Do I need the definite article here?

I'm tempted to use it because I feel an elision of the words "monoclonal antibody", that is, "the ABC-12 monoclonal antibody".

But since it's a proper noun, maybe the version without "the" would be more proper.

> This study compares the immunotoxic effects of repeated administration of two monoclonal antibodies, **ABC-12** (RusBio, lot #1023) and Herceptin (Hoffmann-La Roche, Switzerland), to rhesus macaques (Macaca mulatta).

Comment: Ditch it, it's not required. There's only one kind of ABC-12 .... so the article "the" is not required to mark the NP as definite. Note btw, that the appositive NP in your example is more specifically a 'supplementary' (non-defining)  appositive, not a modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is analogous to the question about `(the) Minkowski spaces` of the other day.

I don't know anything about the drugs mentioned, but I assume from its alphanumeric designation that ABC-12 is experimental and from its brand name that Herceptin is a commercially established drug.

Something new to the scene and lacking a proper "proper name" might use "the", which would corroborate its novelty, its not-yet-established state, and something well established, with a proper proper name, like Herceptin, would tend not to have "the".

Answer (score 1):

The determinant "the" is not necessary.

If you do use it, you may want to think about also placing a "the" in front of "Herceptin" to keep parallel construction.

> This study compares the immunotoxic effects of repeated administration of two monoclonal antibodies, **the** ABC-12 (RusBio, lot #1023) and **the** Herceptin (Hoffmann-La Roche, Switzerland), to rhesus macaques (Macaca mulatta).

however using two "the"s sounds awkward.  You could explicitly enumerate your list of two using "1)" and "2)".

You might reformulate your sentence as

> This study compares the immunotoxic effects of repeated administration of two monoclonal antibodies to rhesus macaques (Macaca mulatta): ABC-12 (RusBio, lot #1023) and Herceptin (Hoffmann-La Roche, Switzerland).

so the monkeys aren't hanging off the end of the sentence.

I don't think there is a "-" in ABC12.